# Please help me with the following pandas data frame manipulation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe as follow:
`

```
`pd.DataFrame({
            'location':['Hyd','Mum','Viz'],
            'rank1':[1,2,3],
            'rank2':[np.NaN,1,2],
})
```

it will look like this:

```
    location    rank1   rank2
0   Hyd         1       NaN
1   Mum         2       1
2   Viz         3       2
```

now I want to add a column ' source' such that it will look like below

```
    location    rank1   rank2   source
0   Hyd         1       NaN     Mum
1   Mum         2       1       Viz
2   Viz         3       2       none
```

as you can see above in the first column we got Mum because rank1  = 1 in the first row  = rank2 in the 2nd row which has location Mum so we allocated mum to source in the first column and the same for others
Please  help me with it
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The following code should work and as it is rank, assuming that it is a unique value, then 'Source' column is bound to have 'nan' in the last row.

```
# let x be the dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x=pd.DataFrame({
            'location':['Hyd','Mum','Viz'],
            'rank1':[1,2,3],
            'rank2':[np.NaN,1,2],
})

# Make an empty list of source
source=[]

# Loop over the 'rank1'
for i in x['rank1']:
  # for every i in rank1
  # find the index of row with i in rank2
  # (yes, index will be very next one,
  #  provided that the data is sorted) 
  try:
    source.append(x['location'][list(x['rank2']).index(i)])
  # as the last value in rank1 
  # will not be present in rank2
  # catch this error and append with nan
  except:
    source.append(np.NaN)

# once source list is ready,
# make a new column and fill these values

x['Source']=source
```